# search the values in array in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays

I have the array like:

```
(
  {
    id=1;
    Title="AAAA";
    period_id=1;
  },
  {
    id=2;
    Title="BBBB";
    period_id=2;
  },
  {
    id=3;
    Title="CCCC";
    period_id=2;
  },
  {
    id=4;
    Title="DDDD";
    period_id=2;
  },
  {
    id=5;
    Title="EEEE";
    period_id=3;
  },
)
```

**Question**: How can i know that `Period_id=2` is multiple times in the array?

Help me solve this.

Thank you,

Comment: do you want to know how to find duplications in the array?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName,Thanks for your reply.. I know that but only fetch the whole object as duplicate. I just want to fetch the duplicate for the particular value.

Comment: once check my answer you'l fine answer.

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of ways to do so, Some of them are here ..

**A:**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"period_id == %@", @"2"];
NSArray *newArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%d", [newArray count]);
```

**B:**

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (id obj in array)
{
    if([obj[@"period_id"] isEqualToString:@"2"]){
        [newArray addObject:obj];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%d", [newArray count]);
```

**C:**

```
NSArray *allIds = [array valueForKey:@"period_id"];
NSCountedSet *set = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:allIds];
for (id item in set)
{
    NSLog(@"period_id=%@, Count=%d", item,[set countForObject:item]);
}
```

**D:**

```
NSArray *allIds = [array valueForKey:@"period_id"];
__block NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *valueToCheck = @"2";
[allIds enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
   if([obj isEqualToString:valueToCheck])
       [newArray addObject:obj];
}];
NSLog(@"%d", [newArray count]);
```

**E:**

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"period_id"] isEqualToString:@"2"];
}];
NSArray *newArray = [array objectsAtIndexes:indexes];
NSLog(@"%d", [newArray count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
 NSIndexSet *indices = [questionSections indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [[obj objectForKey:@"period_id"] isEqualToString:@"2"];
    }];
     NSArray *filtered = [questionSections objectsAtIndexes:indices];

    NSLog(@"duplictae:%d\n %@",[indices count],filtered);
```

O/P:-

```
duplicate: 3
 (
        {
        name = bbbb;
        "period_id" = 2;
    },
        {
        name = ccccc;
        "period_id" = 2;
    },
        {
        name = ddddd;
        "period_id" = 2;
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But i got the error because period_id is Integer.

Comment: Undoubtedly it's unrecognized selector, since it will be an NSNumber instead of an NSString in this case (according to OP)

Comment: then type caste your object and pass string in return condition.

Comment: use `return [[obj objectForKey:@"period_id"].integerValue == 2];` instead. It will caste obj to integer either it `NSString` or `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

if the array is sorted, as it seems at your case, just check if the next item has the same value as this one

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i].id == array[i + 1].id) {
        // Duplicate
    }
}
```

if you just want to know about `id = 2`

```
int idCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i].id == 2) {
        idCount++;
    }
}
```

if you also want to know the location

```
int idCount = 0;
int idarr[array.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (array[i].id == 2) {
        idarr[idCount++] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Syntax doesn't match with **Objective-C**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a **JSON** response from what I gather. Yes you can get the **period_id**. Add all the **period_id's** in an `NSMutableArray`.

Then simply search for the **period_id** from within this array for the values of the **period_id** to be same . You will get the index on which the **period_id's** are same.

```
 NSSet *uniqueElements = [NSSet setWithArray:myArray];

for(id element in uniqueElements) {
  // iterate here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `NSPredicate` to check duplicate.

Try this Example:

```
NSPredicate *testPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"period_id.intValue == %d",value];
NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *testArray= [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:testPredicate];
NSLog(@"duplicate:%d",[testArray count]);
```